# Group items in column by common value then display as a percentage

Tags: mysql, sql, metabase

I have a table such as this

```
id - type
1  - cat
2  - dog
3  - mouse
4  - cat
5  - cat
6  - cat
7  - mouse
```

I want a query which will result in a table like this

```
type  - total - percentage 
cat   - 4     - 57.14
dog   - 1     - 14.28
mouse - 2     - 28.57
```

I cant use the OVER() function or WINDOWS function.
Ive looked at very many posts but none of the queries work for me.
I cant seem to figure this out. Any ideas/help??

Answer (score 1):

you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  (COUNT(*)/x.m)*100 AS percentage
  ,`type
FROM  yourTable
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) as m from  yourTable ) x
GROUP BY `type`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate and then use a window functions to calculate the overall ratio:

```
select type, count(*),
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as percentage
from t
group by type;
```

The above requires MySQL 8+.  In older versions, one method uses two aggregations:

```
select type, count(*),
       count(*) * 100.0 / x.total_cnt as percentage
from t cross join
     (select count(*) as total_cnt from t) x
group by type;
```

Comment: Doesnt work for me, cant use the over function

Comment: @LFED why not ? which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: im using metabase v0.40.1 I cant see which version of mysql I am using, dont have admin rights

Comment: @LFED you can run `select version();` . but when you say it doesn't work , be more specific

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use window function:

```
select type, count(*),
       count(*) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from t) as percentage
from t
group by type;
```

to answer to your comment:

```
select case when type in ('cat','dog') then 'cat & dog' else type end, count(*),
       count(*) * 100.0 / x.total_cnt as percentage
from t
cross join (select count(*) as total_cnt from t) x
group by case when type in ('cat','dog') then 'cat & dog' else type end;
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the query. A follow up if I may. If I wanted to put cat & dog in a bucket and mouse in a separate bucket, how could I do that? Similar to the table below


```
type         - total - percentage 
cat/dog   - 5     - 71.42
mouse     - 2     - 28.57
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight!! Really appreciated. Might you have further insight with regards to a new question I posted located here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68785377/filtering-a-joined-table

Comment: @LFED sure , please accept/ upvote the answer if it helped you