# Filtering a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, metabase

I have two tables

```
Events
id - published
--------------
1  - T
2  - T
3  - F
```

```
Attributes
id - event_id - type
---------------------
1  -   1      - large
2  -   1      - large
3  -   1      - medium
4  -   2      - small
5  -   2      - small
6  -   3      - large
7  -   3      - large
```

What I am trying to do is join these two tables on Events.id and Attributes.event_id & filter like this:

```
For all events where Events.published = True and
where Attributes.type != large or medium
get the percentage of those events which fit the filters / all events
```

```
output of sql query
event_type                    - totals - event_ids - percentage
-----------------------------------------
"events that fit filter"      - 2      - [1,2]     - 66.66% -- (2/3)
"events that dont fit filter" - 1      - [3]       - 33.33% -- (1/3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    case when e.published and a.type not in('large','medium') then 'Met condition' else 'Not met condition' end conditions
    , count(distinct e.id) totals
    , group_concat(distinct e.id) event_ids
    , count(distinct e.id) * 100.0 / x.total_cnt percentage
from events e
join Attributes a on a.event_id = e.id
cross join (select count(*) as total_cnt from events) x
group by case when e.published and a.type not in('large','medium') then 'Met condition' else 'Not met condition' end, total_cnt
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f4b65dddb96a20f53e12a942b88a93c)*

Comment: This was super helpful!! Thank you @eshirvana

Answer (score 0):

> For all events where Events.published = True and
> where Attributes.type != large or medium
> get the percentage of those events which fit the filters / all events

```
select avg( e.published and a.type not in ('large', 'medium') )
from events e join
     attributes a
     on e.id = a.event_id;
```

This uses the fact that MySQL treats booleans as `1` for true and `0` for false.

EDIT:

Oh, you want this *per event*.  For that, use two levels of aggregation:

```
select avg(flag)
from (select e.id, 
             max( e.published and a.type not in ('large', 'medium') ) as flag
      from events e join
           attributes a
           on e.id = a.event_id
      group by e.id
     ) e;
```